# Why doesn't this code using useState() work as intended?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm referring to the snippet in useEffect in the for loop at the last line. After I ran the code once and I console.logged the grids state with the button I rendered I'd get an array with only the number 196.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Gameboard = () => {
  const [grids, setGrids] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setGrids([]);
    for (let i = 0; i < 196; i++) {
      const grid = i + 1;
      setGrids([...grids, grid]);
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="game-board">
    <button onClick={() => console.log(grids)}>click</button>
      {grids.map(grid => (
        <div key={ grid }></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default Gameboard;
```

Now I know how to fix that:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Gameboard = () => {
  const [grids, setGrids] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setGrids([]);
    for (let i = 0; i < 196; i++) {
      const grid = i + 1;
      setGrids(grids => [...grids, grid]);
    }
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div className="game-board">
      {grids.map(grid => (
        <div key={ grid }></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default Gameboard;
```

So the latter one works. That's clear. But why is it? Can someone explain me how this:

setGrids([...grids, grid]);

and this:

setGrids(grids => [...grids, grid]);

works? And why do we get good results with the last one unlike with the other. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using the state variable in the setter function. Common practice is to use a variable called `prevState` (or something else, but `prevState` is frequently used in this kind of situations).

```
setGrids(prevState => [...prevState, grid])
```

So your code will look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // setGrids([]); // Don't need this because is already initialized to []
    for (let i = 0; i < 196; i++) {
      const grid = i + 1;
      setGrids(prevState => [...prevState, grid]);
    }
  }, [])
```

Or may be try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 196; i++) {
      const grid = i + 1;
      temp.push(grid);
    }
    setGrid(temp);
  }, [])
```

So you only set the state once at the end of the loop and avoid unnecessary re-renders. But that will depend on your use case.

Comment: Thansk for correcting me! Also I was using setGrids([]) because in development mode useEffect() runs twice and this way I got double the amount of grids I needed. Is it a bad practice or shall I just add a comment to describe what it does so it can be removed before production?

Comment: In the meantime I realised that your method basically answered my question. So never mind I know what to do. Thanks again!

Comment: If double the amount of grids is the intended result keep the setter in the useEffect hook, is not bad practice but it was not clear what the intention for it was. If my method got the results you need do you mind marked as the accepted answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

setGrids([...grids, grid]); this one has the value of state but it needs to be rerendered to get a new value of state

for example you called setGrids() with new value  for the first time and the component is not rerendered yet so you value of grid is not changed yet
but in this way setGrids(grids => [...grids, grid]); you are telling the setter function to use the value of grid even if it's not rerendered

Comment: And is it because useState() runs asynchronously? (Sorry if I missed the point.)